# Is the term "adeal" ever used in ring theory?

Tags: ring-theory, soft-question, terminology

I'm making my way through Burton's *A First Course in Rings and Ideals* (1970). In this book, a ring need not have an identity. Anyway, in problem 27 of the second chapter (p.38), he introduces the concept of an *adeal*:

> A nonempty subset $A$ of a ring $R$ is termed an *adeal* of $R$ if
> (i) $a, b \in A$ imply $a + b \in A$,
> (ii) $r \in R$ and $a \in A$ imply both $ar \in A$ and $ra \in A$.

When, however, I perform the obvious searches on Google for this term, all I come up with is Burton's book.

Is this concept defunct?
Does it go by another name?

For the person who wanted it, here is the question:

> Prove that
> a) An adeal $A$ of $R$ is an ideal of $R$ if for each $a \in A$ there is an integer $n \neq 0$, depending upon $a$, such that $na \in aR + Ra$. (This condition is satisfied, in particular, if $R$ has a multiplicative identity.)
> b) Whenever $R$ is a commutative ring, the condition in part (a) is a necessary as well as sufficient condition for an adeal to be an ideal.

[screenshot of text in case of typos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1bjM.jpg)

Comment: Please don't add math as images. They can't be searched for. You should typeset all math in your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I'd like to see this problem in its entirety (it is cut off in the image). I also agree question would improve if no image used but typed in the question.

Comment: Those are usually called  "two-sided ideals". Please, next time at least make the effort of type your question instead of using images.

Comment: Sorry, this was my first ever question! I did not know such screen shots of maths were frowned on! All typed out know.

Comment: @jjagmath: If you allow rings to not have a unity, and $R$ does not have a unity, then (i) may fail to imply that the subset is a subgroup, giving you only that it is a submonoid. Usualy (i) suffices because we  an obtain the inverse of $a$ by multiplying by $-1$.

Comment: Does Burton allow rings to not have a unity?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Yes, unity not required. Burton's is a book about rngs.

Comment: As far as I know this is not a common term; the main difference between this concept and an ideal is that you are only requiring the set to be submonoid of the additive group of $R$, whereas an ideal requires it to be a subgroup. They would play the role of ideals for semirings, but the latter seem to just be called "ideals".

Comment: In other words, the forgetful functor $U : \mathbf{Ring} \to \mathbf{Rig}$ is applied (and as usual, this process is not written down and therefore, well, forgotten). This is not a concept in the theory of rings, it is a concept in the theory of (non-unital) rigs, restricted (why?) to rigs which happen to be the image of $U$.

Comment: Thank you, Arturo and Martin!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching MathSciNet for "adeal" anywhere (including both titles and reviews) produced just one result:

MR1532157
Luh, Jiang;
Classroom Notes: Ideals and Adeals of a Ring.
Amer. Math. Monthly 70 (1963), no. 5, 548–550.

So the answer to the title of the question, is it **ever** used, is yes. But it's not used much; in particular, it's not used enough for me to have heard of it before this question.